# curly braces inside parameter call. >> what does it mean? | Spring 3 and GWT

Tags: java, spring, gwt

### question

When the code segment "new TextColumn(){...}, "MyObjectId");" executes then what does the code inside the outermost of pair curly braces represent? Does it represent an anonymous inner class instance of the TextColumn object? Does it represent the definition of the TextColumn object?

### code

```
table.addColumn(new TextColumn<MyObjectProxy>() {
    Renderer<Integer> renderer = new AbstractRenderer<Integer>() {
        public String render(Integer obj) {
            return obj == null ? "" : String.valueOf(obj);
        }
    };
    @Override
    public String getValue(MyObjectProxy object) {
        return renderer.render(object.getMyObjectId());
    }
}, "MyObjectId");
```

if you are wondering the TextColumn is from the com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.TextColumn package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an anonymous inner class that extends `TextColumn<MyObjectProxy>`.  In it, it has a field named `renderer` of type `Renderer<Integer>` that is initialized with an instance of an anonymous inner class that extends `AbstractRenderer<Integer>`.  There is also an override of method `getValue` below that.

Comment: When you say the anonymous inner class extends the `code`TextColumn<>`code` object then is it similar to the extension of a class in a class declaration like `code` public class TextColumn<?> extends TextColumnSuperClass `code` ?

Comment: Yes, but the resulting class is *anonymous*, meaning you can't really directly reference it elsewhere.  (tip: in answers and comments, put backticks around things to `quote them in monospaced font` like code)

Comment: And just to be clear, it's not "extend[ing] the `TextColumn` object" it's extending the `TextColumn` class.  An object is an instance of a class.

Answer (score 2):

It simply defines an anonym class and creates an instance of it. This instance is passed as parameter to the method `table.addColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an anonymous class, corresponding to the TextColumn Object.

The getValue() method is overriden.